# Find sequential limits of $f(x,y)=\log_x(x+y)$ at $(a,b)=(1,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Finding the sequential limit of $f(x,y)=\log_x(x+y)$ at $(a,b)=(1,0)$ is easy as show below:

$$
\lim_{x\to1}\lim_{y\to 0}\log_x{x+y}=\lim_{x\to1}\log_xx=1
$$

My question is with $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to1}\lim_{x\to1}\log_x{(x+y)}$.

Wolfram|Alpha says *Indeterminate form* while the answer in my book is $\infty$. Which one is correct and how can I reach that conclusion?

Comment: It is indeterminate in the sense that the inner $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x,y)$ do not exist in general.

Comment: We have $\lim_{y\to 0}\log_{y+1}((y+1)+y) = 2$.  Perhaps you can do other curves approaching $(1,0)$.  Using this you can get any value in $(1,+\infty)$ as a limit for $x=ky+1$ when $y \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $y > 0$ we have
$$
\log_x(x+y) = \frac{\ln(1+y)}{x-1} + O(1)
\qquad\text{as }x \to 1
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\log_x(x+y) = +\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\log_x(x+y) = -\infty
$$

Comment: From what follows first equality?

Comment: $\log_x(x+y) = \ln(x+y)/\ln(x)$.  Laurent series for this at $x=1$.

Comment: $O(1)$ part can't understand?